# How do you search through a vector and obtain the position of an element in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int search(vector<int>& numbers, int numToFind){
    int numberSize = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberSize; i++){
        if(numbers.at(i) == numToFind){
            return i;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

My function search is supposed to go search through a vector for numToFind and if it finds it, it returns the position.  However, when I run this function, it keeps giving me -1.

Comment: Are they sorted? `std::binary_search`. Else, `std::find`. No reason to code it yourself. But at least make the vector `const`. You don't modify it.

Comment: They are unsorted e.g. 3 10 9 2 5 0.

Comment: What is 'fox'? Looks like you should be comparing to 'numToFind' instead.

Comment: I understand why I shouldn't have the return -1 so early in as it only compares the first value of the vector.  As for making sure -1 means no data is found, I am not sure how I would be able to check that.

Answer (score 5):

You return -1 too early. Your function doesn't even search the rest of the vector.

```
int search(std::vector<int>& numbers, int numToFind){
    int numberSize = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberSize; i++){
        if(numbers.at(i) == numToFind){
            return i;
        }
        // A return statement here would cut the loop too early
    }
    return -1; // Didn't find anything
}
```

If you want a one-based index, return `i + 1` instead.